# Do JAX WS implementation classes come as part of the Java 5/6 package or only as part of an application server libraries?

Tags: java, web-services, java-ee

Do JAX WS implementation classes come as part of the Java5 package, as part of the Java6 package or only as part of an application server libraries like WAS?

I read that it comes as part of Java EE? What does that mean? Java 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-WS is an API which is part of both JavaEE 5 and JavaEE 6 APIs. The implementation of JAX-WS is not part of the JavaEE API. There are multiple implementations of the JAX-WS; noticeable ones are:

- Metro - the reference implementation, and part of the Glassfish application server (it is open-source so you can [easily find sources](https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk))
- CXF - part of an Apache open-source project ([easily found sources](http://cxf.apache.org/source-repository.html))